# updateOrCreate() not updating but adding new

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to update inserted data. But it's not quite working. If the data in the $variable changed then `updateOrCreate` method is just creating a new row. But it's supposed to be update the existed column?

```
$placeItems = [
    "website_id" => self::WEBSITE_ID,
    "url" => $place,
    "place_name" => $title,
    "image" => $image,
    "description" => "I am changing here",
];

Place::updateOrCreate($placeItems);
```

I changed the `description` column. And use `updateOrCreate`, but it's not update the id of description in. Insert it as new. The way i am using updateOrCreate is wrong?

### UPDATED

I tried a way as mentioned in the answer below and test it.

```
$description = "new data";

$placeItems = [
    "website_id" => self::WEBSITE_ID,
    "url" => $place,
    "place_name" => $title,
    "image" => $image,
    "description" => "old data",
];

Place::updateOrCreate([
    "website_id" => self::WEBSITE_ID,
    "url" => $place,
    "place_name" => $title,
    "image" => $image,
    "description" => $description,
], $placeItems);
```

But it still inserting as new column. not updating the ID of description in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you should specify parameters for updatedOrCreate.

The first parameter indicates the conditions for a match and second parameter specify which fields to update.

```
Place::updateOrCreate([ "website_id"=> self::WEBSITE_ID], [
     "url" => $place,
    "place_name" => $title,
    "image" => $image,
    "description" => $description]);
```

Read documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

Comment: I tried and test it, but it still is the same. I update the code in the question, could you please check it out. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @tate i updated my answer also read the sample in documentation